# Convert XML to JSON in laravel

Tags: json, xml, laravel

I am just trying to learn laravel so please guide me how to resolve this issue

I want to convert XML data to JSON format.

But, XML code is converted to TEXT from instead of JSON format.

I am getting this data from my device API [it is a biometric device, I used it's API to fetch XML data]

**My code**

```php
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://192.168.1.50/device.cgi/events?action=getevent&roll-over-count=0&seq-number=".$seqnumber."&no-of-events=1&format=xml");
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($response);
```

**My output**

```sh
    0 29 27/6/2019 13:39:41 164 1 0 20 0 0
```

It is in text format,

I want this output in JSON format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml_file = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml_file );
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

Comment: Is it working with device API? Because my XML data is generated from the device API so how can I integrate or add my code with this solution?

Comment: If you have xml response string then you can add xml string as $xmlstring

Comment: Okay, I will try to look into it

Comment: If you wants to parse the data from xml then simplexml_load_string() function helps to converts xml string to object.For your code you have xml string so for that you have to convert this xml string to object and this function converts xml string to object